# Как сделать плавное наведение?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Не могу понять почему не работает плавная анимация на background,а на border работает.

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;margin:35px 170px;
}


a.da {
    background: 0 0;
    border-color: #f2a309;
    color: #fff;
}

.btnn {
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: raleway, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    /* border-radius: 20px; */
    padding: 8px 30px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    transition: .5s ease-out all;
    
}
.da:hover {
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,#38acbf 0%,#f2a309 100%);
    border-color: transparent;
    background-origin: border-box;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<a class="btnn da" href="#">Read More</a>
```

Comment: На сколько я знаю градиенты еще не поддерживают `transition`

Comment: Если тебе необходимо сделать плавное появление градиент фона, пробуй это сделать через opacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться псевдоэлементом, ему задать фон в виде градиента, а по наведению - менять прозрачность:

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    margin:35px 170px;
}
a.da {
    background: 0 0;
    border-color: #f2a309;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
a.da:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,#38acbf 0%,#f2a309 100%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease-out all;
}
a.da span {
  position: relative;
}
.btnn {
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: .08em;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: raleway, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    transition: .5s ease-out all;
}
.da:hover {
    border-color: transparent;
    background-origin: border-box;
    color: #ffffff;
}
a.da:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a class="btnn da" href="#"><span>Read More</span></a>
```

Только чтобы текст не пропадал при наведении, нужно обернуть его в span и задать position: relative

Comment: да, но дело в том что бордер нужен, а тут получается что он исчезает

Comment: @AndriiSoldatenko, в смысле? Он же и в Вашем примере исчезает: у Вас по наведению стоит border-color: transparent;

Comment: @AndriiSoldatenko, или Вы в том смысле, чтобы фон накладывался в том числе и на исчезающий бордер? Тогда поправил ответ

Comment: Последнее то что вы сказали! Именно так

Comment: @AndriiSoldatenko, ну так я уже изменил ответ: можете смело его принимать :)